# Building a SOAP client in Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I want to use, with Java, a SOAP API, that receives a XML like this one, to cal a method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Body>
        <GetReturnAnalysis xmlns="http://www.address.com/integration">
            <entityCode>186D3CAD-0841</entityCode>
        </GetReturnAnalysis>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

In order to do that, I've created the folllowing class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetReturnAnalysis")
public class GetReturnAnalysisRequest {
  @XmlElement(name = "entityCode")
  protected String entityCode;
  @XmlAttribute(name="xmlns", required = true)
  public final static String xmlns="http://www.address.com/integration";

  public GetReturnAnalysisRequest(String entityCode) {
    this.entityCode = entityCode;
  }

  public GetReturnAnalysisRequest() { }

  public String getEntityCode() {
    return entityCode;
  }

  public void setEntityCode(String entityCode) {
    this.entityCode = entityCode;
  }        
}
```

And made the following code to build the message to be sent:

```
private  SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(GetReturnAnalysis request) throws SOAPException, JAXBException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance("SOAP 1.2 Protocol");
    SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    message.getSOAPHeader().detachNode();

    SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
    String requestString =  XmlHelper.toOutputString(request);
    Document doc = convertStringToDocument(requestString);
    body.addDocument(doc);
    message.writeTo(System.out);

    message.saveChanges();
    message.writeTo(System.out);


    return message;
  }
```

(The methods called internally, in this code):

```
public static <T> String toOutputString(T type) throws IOException {
    Validate.notNull(type, "Java type not defined!");

    try {
      StringWriter os = new StringWriter();
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(type.getClass());
      Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

      // output pretty printed
      jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
      jaxbMarshaller.marshal(type, os);

      System.out.println(os.toString());

      return os.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      throw new IOException(e);
    }
  }




private Document convertStringToDocument(String xml) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    return DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
  }
```

It should work, in my point of view. However, it generates a XML like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Body>
        <GetReturnAnalysis xmlns="">
            <entityCode>186D3CAD-0841</entityCode>
        </GetReturnAnalysis>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And the server doesn't accept that, since it doesn't have the xmlns="http://www.address.com/integration" attribute filled. I wonder if it is due to the name of the attribute (xmlns)... However, this is the name the server expects, and I can't change it, since it is a third party API.

I've also tried to make it differently, declaring the class like this:

```
  @XmlRootElement(name = "GetReturnAnalysis", namespace = "http://www.address.com/integration")
  public class GetReturnAnalysisRequest { ...
```

But when I'm adding to the message (body.addDocument method), it retrieves an error (there shouldn't be a namespace there).

On the code, as you might have noticed, I've put two message.writeTo (for debug, on createSOAPRequest method). The first one gives me the XML correctly, the seccond one, after I call "save", I get the xml with the xmlns attribute empty on GetReturnAnalysis.

I wonder if you could help me with that. I'm a noob with SOAP, and having a lot of trouble with this issue...

**UPDATE 1**

I've successfully sent a message, using postman, with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns="http://www.address.com/integration" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Body>
        <GetReturnAnalysis >
            <entityCode>186D3CAD-0841</entityCode>
        </GetReturnAnalysis>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

So I've made a small change on the code, changing the class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetReturnAnalysis")
public class GetReturnAnalysisRequest {
  @XmlElement(name = "entityCode")
  protected String entityCode;

  public GetReturnAnalysisRequest(String entityCode) {
    this.entityCode = entityCode;
  }

  public GetReturnAnalysisRequest() { }

  public String getEntityCode() {
    return entityCode;
  }

  public void setEntityCode(String entityCode) {
    this.entityCode = entityCode;
  }        
}
```

and the create SOAP request method:

```
private  SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(GetReturnAnalysis request) throws SOAPException, JAXBException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance("SOAP 1.2 Protocol");
    SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("", "http://www.address.com/integration");
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    message.getSOAPHeader().detachNode();

    SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
    String requestString =  XmlHelper.toOutputString(request);
    Document doc = convertStringToDocument(requestString);
    body.addDocument(doc);
    message.writeTo(System.out);

    message.saveChanges();
    message.writeTo(System.out);    

    return message;
  }
```

However, for some misterious reason, when I call message.saveChanges, the GetReturnAnalysis class ends up like this:

```
<GetReturnAnalysis xmlns="">
    <EntityCode>186D3CAD-0841</EntityCode>
</GetReturnAnalysis>ityCode>
```

and the empty xmlns attribute overrides the overall namespace I provided. I wonder why it does that? Couldn't it simply save the string I wanted to save, without changes??

Comment: You have to define namespace of the request object. But I'd suggest to go through the whole WS lifecycle. Staring with having WSDL, generating a client class and message objects and use object level API to call or expose web services. I'd advice to use some mature framework, such as Axis2 or CXF (my preferred).

Comment: Could you post the error/exception?

Comment: The response, when I call with the empty attribute: Response SOAP Message ...<soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize() ...
</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault>...

Comment: The exception message, When I try to put namespace on the class: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.

Comment: @gusto2 I am searching on how to define a namespace for that object, but I didn't find how yet. I believe this would solve it for me...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado: I believe the namespace in the XmlRootElement is valid approach, what exception did you get for that? Still I'd advice to use a framework (cxf, axis2) to generate a client and classes from WSDL (really try to make). It will ensure the protocol and all the serialization is done properly. Or create an interface and generate wsdl and a client from the interface. See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html.

Comment: The exception I get when I try to add namespace in the XmlRootElement is `NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces`

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado  I see three possible issues. First is the XmlHelper. We don't see what does it produce (maybe the namespace is already skipped there. Second - the DocumentFactory - you need to set "setNamespaceAware(true)" on it. Third - you're really overcomplicating things not using a framework. Really invest some time to learn it and save a lot in future. I'd use direct XML handling only in very special cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your code

Namespace definition:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetReturnAnalysis", namespace = "http://www.address.com/integration")
public class GetReturnAnalysisRequest {
  @XmlElement(name = "entityCode", namespace = "http://www.address.com/integration")
  protected String entityCode;

  public GetReturnAnalysisRequest(String entityCode) {
    this.entityCode = entityCode;
  }

  public GetReturnAnalysisRequest() { }

  public String getEntityCode() {
    return entityCode;
  }

  public void setEntityCode(String entityCode) {
    this.entityCode = entityCode;
  }   
}
```

Second - set the document builder as namespace aware

```
String requestString =  toOutputString(request);

Document doc = convertStringToDocument(requestString);
body.addDocument(doc);
message.writeTo(System.out);
```

-

```
private Document convertStringToDocument(String xml) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    return docFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
  }
```

Use framework

For consuming web services REALLY you should use a framework. I'd advice [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html) (my preferred) or [Axis2](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html).  Then you can define a service interface and generate proper wsdl and client classes plus you get support for other optional protocols and extensions (e.g. security).

Handling XML directly I'd advice only in special cases, such as RPC-literal, custom security or other not-anymore-supported protocols.